# How do I make my chat program scroll down as the chat moves along?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, chat

I'm making a simple chat GUI. I've come into a problem where my program isn't scrolling down as the chat moves along. I'm also unsure about how to add a scroll bar/pane to the program, without messing everything up by putting my main text area into a panel and destroying the look of the interface. How do I adjust the main chat box, without screwing it up and making it look ugly by putting the `chatBox` in a JPanel. I'll post all of my code below.

MainGUI class:

```
package coltGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainGUI implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MainGUI gui = new MainGUI();
        gui.display();
    }

    JButton sendMessage;
    JTextField messageBox;
    JTextArea chatBox;

    public void display() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colt Chat");
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southPanel);
        southPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        southPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        messageBox = new JTextField(30);
        sendMessage = new JButton("Send Message");
        chatBox = new JTextArea();
        chatBox.setEditable(false);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, chatBox);

        chatBox.setLineWrap(true);

        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        right.weightx = 2.0;

        southPanel.add(messageBox, left);
        southPanel.add(sendMessage, right);

        sendMessage.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(470, 300);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (messageBox.getText().length() < 1) {
            // do nothing 
        } else {
            chatBox.append(messageBox.getText() + "\n");
            messageBox.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to edit your `GridBagConstraints` a little, so the input field gets wider: http://pastebin.com/6hmscQbQ

Comment: @Lonenebula Can you be a little bit more specific? I took a look at your pastebin, but I'm not sure what you want me to do.

Comment: The witdh of the `messageBox` is 0 in the code above. Maybe some look-and-feels would still show the letters you type in, but that wasn't the case for me. Replacing the code where you set the left and right `GridBagCounstraints` with the code in the pastebin, would fix that. (Assuming you want `messageBox` to fill the empty space in `southPanel`). However, that would make the `messageBox` cover up the blue background behind it.

Comment: @Lonenebula Covering up the blue behind it is what I want, it makes the `messageBox` look like it has an outline, which I kinda like. Thanks for being specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the text area to a JScrollPane and then add the scrollpane to the frame. There is no need for a panel.

```
//frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, chatBox);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(chatBox), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Note that constraints should be specified as the second parameter of the add(...) method, not the first.

Also, since JDK5, you don't need to use getContentPane(), the frame.add(..) method will do this for you.

If you want automatic scrolling you can check out [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to wrap `chatBox` in a `JScrollPane` like this:

```
frame.add(new JScrollPane(chatBox), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Second after appending the message to `chatBox` you need to force it to scroll to the end which can be done with the following:

```
chatBox.setCaretPosition(chatBox.getDocument().getLength());
```

Comment: Since Java 1.5, it's not been required to use `frame.getContentPane()`, `frame.add` is more then sufficient...

Comment: Thanks, I updated that and also flipped around the parameters for `add` which camickr pointed out.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I personally like to use frame.getContentPane, as it just seems more organized. Unless I'm not using any BorderLayout functionality. Screw it then, just use `frame.add`